# Can someone help me with figure highlight?

Tags: floats

I want to know if there is a way to use box at multiple location inside a figure. I figured out how to hightlight one location by using node. But I need to add few more boxes to two subfloats so that I can compare them. Below is the figure. I added one red box and I want add 10 more of them to both top and bottom figure. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Welcome! If you know how to highlight one location, can't you just apply this knowledge ten times to highlight ten?

Comment: I take it you want to use `axis cs:` for the horizontal coordinates and `rel axis cs:` for the top and bottom.  You can also name the axis and use `(name.north)` and `(name.south)`.  Then just define the perpendicular intersections `(a |- b)` or `(a -| b)` where a and b are two coordinates (no parentheses).

Comment: I think \node can only use once for each figure since each node imports a image. At least this is the code I got from google. I don’t know how to use multiple node with only one image

Comment: You can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/194703 to draw on any plot. Please show the code that you are using.

Comment: This is the technique I'm using right now. However, whenever I add another draw there will be a line connect the new box with previous ones. Here's my code: 
\begin{figure*}[htp]  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (-4.7,-2.2)  
{\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{"ImpvsOriS2".eps}};
\draw[red,thick] rectangle (0.5,2.5);
\draw[red,thick]  rectangle (2.5,0) -- (3,0) -- (3,2.5) -- (2.5,2.5) -- (2.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Comparison of original and modified QRSDS Method for (a) S1 and (b) S2}
    \label{fig:ImpCompDettest}
\end{figure*}